# ReplaceAll for expressions involving negative power

Tags: replacement, algebra

I have an expression:

$exp=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}-\frac{3}{x^{3}}$

I am trying to make the following replacement:

$\frac{1}{x^{i}}\rightarrow f(i)$, where f is any arbitrary function.

The Mathematica code I have tried is:

```
ReplaceAll[1 + 1/x + 2/x^2 - 3/x^3, x^-i_ :> i]
```

However, this code does not seem to perform any replacement for this case. It is working fine for cases with positive power of x.

Is there any alternative way to make the replacement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
1 + 1/x + 2/x^2 - 3/x^3 /. Power[x, i_] -> f[-i]
(*1 + f[1] + 2 f[2] - 3 f[3]*)
```

Comment: Yup, Its working fine. You are a life saver brother! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @utsabDey You're welcome

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`PatternTest` (`?`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) with [`Negative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Negative.html).

```
ReplaceAll[1 + 1/x + 2/x^2 - 3/x^3, x^i_?Negative :> f[-i]]
```

> ```
> 1 + f[1] + 2 f[2] - 3 f[3]
> ```

and

```
ReplaceAll[1 + x + 2/x^2 - 3/x^3 + x^4, x^i_?Negative :> f[-i]]
```

> ```
> 1 + x + x^4 + 2 f[2] - 3 f[3]
> ```

Hope this helps.